# Ubuntu linux server wont let me scroll/page up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scroll

Everything on my server works perfectly through ssh, using putty. However on both putty and even directly on the servers keyboard I cant page/scroll up using shift+page up. It goes up about half a page then automatically goes back to the bottom where the flashing text entry cursor is.

Comment: It is normal. Use `screen`. If you start an editor like `emacs` you could scroll in it.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, could i also use pico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SSH, the system automatically scrolls down. To review the text view the server log in pico.